# Warning: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 10 by JavaFX runtime version 8

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I wondering how to get rid of these warning message. I reinstalled jdk 8, i ran the project in NetBeans and got the warning message shown below. Will uninstalling jdk 8 and installing java 10 make the warning go away? The program is crashing and there's a lot of javafx runtime messages.

[image: Warning: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 10 by JavaFX runtime version 8]

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 1):

This means that the FXML files are created with SceneBuilder running a Java 10.0.1.
You can download SceneBuilder for Java 8 at [SceneBuilder 8](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/).
However the application should run ok regarding this warning.

Comment: You're saying SceneBuilder is the problem here?

Comment: @michaelgz13 Your FXML file has an `xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1` attribute in the root element. This is automatically added by Scene Builder. If you simply get rid of the `10.0.1`, or replace it with `8.0.241`, then the warning will go away. The version added by Scene Builder corresponds to the version of Scene Builder itself, since the tool's capabilities are determined by which version of JavaFX it was built for. The warning is simply telling you that if you used JavaFX APIs which require 10.0.1 then the application will fail on earlier versions.

Comment: @michaelgz13 However, you also say "_The program is crashing and there's a lot of javafx runtime messages_", which is the more significant problem (though the warning may be related). Perhaps if you edit your question to provide a [mre] and the _exact_ errors we can be of more help.